# Launching an application from another application or resuming it if it's already running

Tags: android, android-intent

Assuming I have 2 applications, A and B.

I'm using PackageManager to launch B from A. However, I want the flow to be resume to whatever the page is if B is already running if B is not running, then launch a new instance of the B. Is it possible to achieve this kind of flow or it will always launch a new instance of the application.

Comment: you can use intent filter to choose what activity to open if other application send the intent to your application. read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
//Get package manager
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();

//Get intent for application
Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.application");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

//Start new application
startActivity(i);
```

It will attempt to run application's launcher, if it is already running it will just resume.

Comment: The behavior is strange though. If the app is opened by the user, and I use B to open the app, it run the splash screen for a short while. However, if the app is opened by B and B is re run to open A again. Splash screen no longer showing.

Comment: @Ophitect I'm not sure I understand what you mean, the behavior depends on how the app you are trying to open is programmed, in theory you can program an app in such a way that even if it is resumed you just initialize everything and it looks like it just started.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `PackageManager#getLaunchIntentForPackage(String)` produces an intent that always starts a new task, never raises the existing one.  If you're seeing the same thing, do this instead:

```
public static Intent newLauncherIntent(final Context context) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    return intent;
}
```

Despite setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, this will raise any existing task.